# Unix system calls to copy all files with the same extension in a folder

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I am very new to programming and would like to post a question/problem I have been struggling with:

I need to write a program in c using unix system calls in order to copy all files with the same extensions in a folder.

I have tried many programs but none seem to do the job. Can you please provide me a solution. It is and I ran out of places to look.

I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void usage(char *name)
{
  printf("Usage: %s <source> <destination>\n", name);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd1, fd2;
  int n;
  char c;

  /*** command line args */
  if(argc!=3)
    {
      usage(argv[0]);
      exit(1);
    }

  /*** open the files */
  if((fd1=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY))<0)
    {
      printf("Error opening input file\n");
      exit(2);
    }
  if((fd2=open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU)) < 0)
    {
      printf("Error creating destination file\n");
      exit(3);
    }

  /*** copy */
  while((n = read(fd1, &c, sizeof(char))) > 0)
    {
      if(write(fd2, &c, n) < 0)
    {
      printf("Error writing to file\n");
      exit(4);
    }
    }

  if(n < 0)
    {
      printf("Error reading from file\n");
      exit(5);
    }

  /*** closing the files */
  close(fd1);
  close(fd2);

  return 0;
}
```

But without success and it returns:

"Error creating destination file"

Please help!

Comment: When `open` fails, what error does it fail with?

Comment: What are you providing for command-line arguments?

Comment: The single file copy works like this: ./copy file1.txt file2.txt. I tried ./copy *.txt /folder/ and does not work.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: I don't know how to answer your question. But when I try to copy a file to a folder it returns:                                                                           ./copy 1.txt  /folder/
Error creating destination file

Comment: @david31 That's because you coded your program to always say that when it has any error no matter what the error is. You need to add code to your program to check what the error is.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: I guess you are right, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: If `argv[2]`is e.g. `/folder/`  like in your example in your comment, the program will try to create the file `/folder/`, but this fails because `/folder/` already exists, it is a folder. Your program can only be invoked with two arguments, both of which must be a _file_. The second file can not exist, in that case it will be created.

Comment: Oh and `./copy *.txt /folder/` can end badly. `*.txt` will be expanded to all .txt filenames in your directory.

Comment: You could use `perror("open")` to print a human readable error, or you could use `strerror(errno)` to get the human readable error string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an easier way:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
int main() 
{ 
char command[50]; 
strcpy(command, "cp -v *.txt ~/folder/folder1"); 
system(command); 
return 0; 
}
```

It does the job. Do you see anything wrong here?

Comment: Is the assignment to use the `system()` function call from the C standard library, or to use actual [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) directly?

Comment: It does not prohibit us from using the system() function call but also it does not specify that we can use it ! It gets the job done !